# jQuery Filter Data Array by Multiple Keys

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter

I have an object array that looks something like:

```
var arr = [{FilterBy: 1, Id: 10, Name: W},
              {FilterBy: 1, Id: 11, Name: X}, 
              {FilterBy: 2, Id: 12, Name: Y}, 
              {FilterBy: 3, Id: 13, Name: Z}];
```

I have a method where I filter the array and pass the parameter "oneId" (which is a single FilterBy id):

```
 var filteredArr = arr.filter(function (x) { return x.FilterBy === oneId });
```

How can I expand this method to accept multiple IDs? I would like to pass an array of FilterByIds (i.e., 1, 2), in which case the result should be:

```
 filteredArr = [{FilterBy: 1, Id: 10, Name: W},
              {FilterBy: 1, Id: 11, Name: X}, 
              {FilterBy: 2, Id: 12, Name: Y}]
```

Not sure if I can do a filter on multiple Ids like that (or don't know how to).

Tried looking, but didn't yield anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was hoping for a one line answer in the filter. I went ahead and did it by just looping over the FilterBy Ids and then pushing one array into the other:

```
 var filterByIds = [] //my array of IDs
 var filteredData = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < filterByIds.length; i++) {
    //var newData = ;
    [].push.apply(filteredData, getFilteredDataArrayBy(selectorToUpdate, parseInt(filterByIds[i])));
}

 function getFilteredDataArrayBy(fieldName, filterById) {
     return filteredDataArr = dataArray[fieldName].filter(function (x) { return x.FilterBy === filterById });
 }
```

If anyone has a one-line succinct piece of code, I'll take it! :)